# Сериализация объектов на c#

Tags: c#, xml

Подскажите кто-нибудь с сериализацией классов на c#.

Например, есть такой участок кода, пример ниже. Не могу понять, если есть такой участок кода и в нем вместо `XmlDataDocument` использовать `XmlSerializer` для создания xml-файла, то как загружать xml в оперативную память?

Если использовать `xmlDoc.Serializer()`, то здесь необходимо передавать два параметра: один объект `FileStream`, а второй какой?

И никак не получается пробегаться по элементам в цикле `for` при сериализации.

```
 public static string[] GetPeopleName()//возвращаем людей
       {
        //Открываем FileStream  
         FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathXml, FileMode.Open,     FileAccess.Read,  FileShare.ReadWrite); //указываем путь к файлу.
        //Создаем Xml документ.
        XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(fs); //загружаем в память данные из файла xml
        ArrayList name_Surname = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            string temp = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText +
                " " + xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("surName").InnerText;
            name_Surname.Add(temp);
        }
        fs.Close();
        return (string[])name_Surname.ToArray(typeof(string));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Особых трудностей при записи и чтении обычных объектов в XML и обратно быть не должно: они автоматически записываются и читаются. Например,

```
public class Point
{
    public string X;
    public string Y;
}

public class Curve
{
    public Point[] Points;
}

public class Sample
{
    private void DoReadWrite(string filename, Curve from, out Curve to)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Curve));

        // Запись
        Stream writer = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        xs.Serialize(writer, from);
        writer.Close();

        // Чтение        
        Stream reader = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        to = (Curve)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Посмотрите [примеры XML-сериализации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/58a18dwa.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, .NET поддерживает несколько сериализаторов. Для работы с xml можно использовать XmlSerializer и DataContractSerializer. XmlSerializer позволяет более гибко управлять форматом xml-файла, в который сохраняются данные, DataContractSerializer позволяет более гибко управлять поведением объекта при сериализации и десериализации. Во-первых, он поддерживает события сериализации и десераилизации, во-вторых, он позволяет динамически формировать список допустимых подтипов сериализуемого типа.

Кроме того, .NET поддерживает форматтеры. Отличие форматтеров от сериализаторов состоит в том, что форматтер, помимо данных, сохраняет в поток реквизиты сериализуемого типа. В реальной практике я использовал BinaryFormatter. Он работает несколько медленнее, чем DataContractSerializer, зато при сериализации массивов обеспечивает практически 100% эффективность по объёму. Например, массив из 1000 интов в сериализованном виде будет весить около 4 килобайт. Но, как видно из названия, на выходе получается бинарник, а не xml.

Answer (score 0):

Создаёте класс, объекты которого можно [превратить](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdxxw552.aspx) в XML и [обратно](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Мораль в том что класс вроде

```
class Person
{
  public string Name;
  public string Surname;
}
```

можно записывать в XML и обратно используя `XmlSerializer`. XML API для чтения тут совсем не нужно :)

Comment: если это в мой огород, то по ссылкам как раз простой пример кода :)